# Is there anyway we can get values from build script and pass it to task in Bambo0 Atlasian?

Tags: maven, build, bamboo

Is there anyway we can get values from build script and pass it to task in Bamboo Atlasian?

Basically I have maven build and try compile in Bamboo 2. I have custom task which executes deployment once code compiled.  The custom build basically requires following parameter to run:

1. Artefact URL
2. Version
   is there anyway we can populate automatically from build?

Thanks
Siddu

Comment: Which version? Maven or the Bamboo number?

Comment: Maven 3 and Bamboo 5.9.  Finally I got it through maven plug-in.

Comment: Yes you can use MavenPomExtractor Plugin